# Android path and path prefix is not working

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

Hi I'm having url like https://myapp.example.io/#/home?ref="myid"&name="myname"&img="myimageurl"&utm_source=invitation&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Invitations.
In my app I coded like

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="https"
          android:host="myapp.example.io"
          android:pathPrefix="/home?ref=" />

    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

I changed pathPrefix to path and to path pattern. Can someone suggest me how to get correct path from this url. So then I can use it to redirect it to my app. Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAICT, in your URL, there is no path. Everything is in a fragment, which is to say, everything after the `#` should be a fragment. You cannot filter on fragments in an `<intent-filter>`. Perhaps there's some rule with URLs where a `#` is now a valid path segment, though a quick scan isn't coming up with anything.

Comment: So how can I able to filter because after myapp.example.io/ i'mhaving different paths.

Comment: If they all have `#` as in your example, I doubt that you can filter on them. You can use the scheme and host to limit your app to that server, but you would have to handle all URLs from that server.

Comment: # is not mandatory, what if I removed # in this url https://myapp.example.io/home?ref="myid"&name="myname"&img="myimageurl"&utm_source=invitation&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Invitations will it work.

Comment: For a URL of the form `https://myapp.example.io/foo/bar.txt?query=params&go=here`, you could use `android:path="/foo/bar.txt"`, `android:pathPrefix="/foo"`, etc. The path attributes in a `<data>` element work solely on the path, not on query parameters, fragments, etc.